# AngularJS | IIFE within controller that calls own method

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure this isn't the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do however it's what I've come up with. I have an init iife that needs to call a method. Both of which are in the same service. How is this done?

Error:

> angular.js:12798 TypeError: that.admin is not a function
>
> ```
> at AuthService.js:8
> at Object.<anonymous> (AuthService.js:12)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:4570)
> at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4422)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:4570)
> at angular.js:4387
> at getService (angular.js:4529)
> at Object.invoke (angular.js:4561)
> at extend.instance (angular.js:9435)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8540)
> ```

Code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('AuthService', function ($localStorage) {

  var that = this;
  var $storage = $localStorage;

  (function () {
    if ($storage.adminHash) {
      return that.admin($storage.adminHash.email, $storage.adminHash.password);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  })();

  return {

    admin: function (email, password) {
      return ...

});
```

Comment: I've also tried placing the iife after the methods but same result.

Comment: So, why do you have `return` in your IIFE if don't assign it anywhere? Btw, in this very case IIFE does not bring any additional semantics. You may remove it and your code would work the same (if you remove useless `return`s)

Comment: Hmm. Are you saying that this iife isn't being invoked?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that wrapping your code into IIFE does not add any benefits here.

Comment: The idea was that by making it an IIFE it would fire whenever the app is launched. So I should make it a named function and then call it?

Comment: Nope, it is invoked exactly after the `var $storage = $localStorage;` line. It is called IIFE because it is an **IMMEDIATELY** invoked function expression.

Comment: Ok so IIFE aside, why is that.admin not a function?

Comment: Well, may be because it's not a function? Not sure what else to add.

Comment: It's a function when I call it from other controllers? I'm obviously missing something....

Comment: Well, you have not provided how you define it. And what `this` refers to.

Comment: I thought 'this' refers to the service.

Comment: What if you check?

Comment: Ahah. I don't know what `that` is... it has an array but using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` I do not see any methods...

Comment: With that said, my question remains. How do I (Or even, can I) call this services methods from within the service?

Comment: `this` refers to service instance in `service` where a function is called as a constructor. It shouldn't be used in `factory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
angular.module('app').factory('AuthService', function($localStorage) {

  var factory = {
    admin: function(email, password) {}
  };

  var $storage = $localStorage;

  if ($storage.adminHash) {
    factory.admin($storage.adminHash.email, $storage.adminHash.password);
  }

  return factory;

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I researched more about factory and learned a bunch.